# opposite to the number 25

Tags: nouns, numbers, antonyms

I cannot make sense of this sentence, namely the *opposite* word in

> Our house is number 25, and theirs is just opposite.

What is opposite to the number 25 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When talking about a house, if another house is "opposite", it means it's directly across the street.

There's no implication about what the house number of the other house is, only that its location is on the other side of the street.

Comment: I live at number 3 in our road. Opposite is number 4.  In the UK, when there are houses on both sides of the same road or street, the houses on one side are usually given odd numbers, and on the opposite side, even numbers.

Comment: Odd-even on opposite sides is very common. But it's not universal. Japan has a wildly different scheme where the numbers on houses in a block are assigned in the order the buildings were constructed.

Comment: In the UK there was a scheme, suggested in the early 1970s, by the Post Office, under which houses would be numbered along each street according to the number of paces the postman would have to walk to each one, again, odd one one side, even on the other, so my side of our road would be something like 11, 33, 55, up to about 600. Completely crazy, universally criticised, and dropped.

Comment: Another possibility is simply their house number.  Our house number is 25. Theirs is 52. Since house numbers are "Even" "Odd" (Even on one side of street, Odd, the other), implication can also be this, even though not implied (America), connotation in house numbering is simply understood as this.

Comment: One reason for this, is as the urban development grows the new properties can be numbered consecutively without any discontinuity, making them easier to find. The low numbers are almost invariably at the 'town' end. In UK there are some streets where the numbering goes up one side and back down the other, but it is uncommon, or where it is impossible to build on both sides of the street (for example by a river).

Comment: @SteveB053, without some kind of context, there's no way I would make the connection that 52 is somehow opposite (not even "the opposite of") 25.